# How to reset mysql column to 0 each 24h?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a website that let users download PDF files,
I made a download limit 10 files per day for each user and I stored the numbers inside MySQL database. everything works great!

**The problem is: The limit will be set forever, I want it to reset to 0 each 24h.
Is there any phpmyadmin command or something to reset that column each 24h to 0 automatically or any other way!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are already storing the download counts in a log table of sorts.

For expiring those counts, I suggest using the event scheduler native to MySQL. You may need to enable it in your server parameters.

Syntax would look something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    DO
      UPDATE count_db.count_table SET count_column = 0;
```

Comment: Yes exaclty but my problem is my hosting provider locked superuser, for that I can't use scheduler

Comment: Which hosting provider are you using? Several will allow you to edit a parameter config or file without giving you access direct to the machine.

Comment: one.com they locked superuser completly on my server

Answer (score 2):

I would try a different way.

I would add table download_log(user_id, file_id, timestamp) and insert row every time user downloads some file.
To check if user reached limit you can check how many downloads he did perform in last 24h.
Something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM download_log WHERE user_id = ? AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

---

To schedule some operations you can use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run script