# How to set values inside column to zero every 24 hour?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a website that let users download PDF files, I made a download limit 10 files per day for each user and I stored the numbers inside MySQL table under column named "downloads".

Each day I use this command to set all values to 0 for all users:

```
update users set downloads = 0
```

I contact my web-host provider and they refused to give me super user privilege to make schedule for this column to reset itself each 24 hour.

Is there any other way to make little code in PHP to reset that column from outside or any other way to do that?

Update: I can not run cron job either!

Comment: Yes you can write program and query in PHP file  and execute it by cron job in your PHP webhosting side 

Their you can set page URL with time

Comment: [Didn't this answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54485788/479156)? That saves you from having a job running and is less error prone.

Comment: @Ivar I can not run cron job either!

Comment: @james That is not what the answer is about. It just mentions that you _could_ use a cronjob but the part above the horizontal line does not require a job at all.

Comment: Just store the user and the time of the download

Answer (score 1):

Save in the database the date and the downloads number in the same field, every time you update this field ask if the date inside is today if not save today's date and zero downloads for example your field will be:

date_downloadsTimes
03-02-2019_2

Answer (score -1):

Store the last reset time in a file or the database and upon every new download request check if the last reset was 24h+ ago. If so, reset the download counter and update the time. That way you are not reliant on a background job.

Alternatively you could set up a route (some URL to be called) that is periodically called from an external source (either your pc or some web service), and resets your download counters.

Comment: So a new database to store date and time! is there any other way to do that without using another mysql table?

Comment: You can add another column to your users table which stores the last reset time. You already store the download count. Another column wouldn't hurt.